# New Eclipse hierarchical package presentation is partially broken

Tags: eclipse, directory, package, treeview

With the new Eclipse release 2022-03 some (but not all) java projects changed appearance in the Project Explorer view. Although Package Presentation is set to Hierarchical, the Project Explorer view still displays long/full package names instead of showing them as a tree of sub-directories (see the screenshot)

[image]

I can't find any reference as to how to control this behavior. This also seems to be project specific as half of my existing projects **in the same workspace** do not exhibit this behavior and display the package hierarchy as expected like directories (see below)

[image]

I just can't find a way to control this.

Comment: Possibly [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=579170)

Comment: @greg-449 You might be right about that. I'll research and then may have to remove the question altogether. Or maybe just leave it as a reference to the bug report

Answer (score 3):

It seems an Eclipse [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=579170) as referred by @greg-449.

Until a fix is provided, the following worked for me as workaround:

- open the project properties
- select "Project Natures"
- remove "Eclipse Faceted Project Properties"

Comment: That would certainly be a solution if it was an option in my case. This indeed looks like an Eclipse regression mentioned by @greg-449 and it is likely related to specific project facets e.g. Dynamic Web Module.

Answer (score 1):

I also have had this problem always with project&package explorer. That's why I kept using Navigator which now has been removed....

The Eclipse bug report was closed as fixed but the problems persist.
They mention removing from the .project file

org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature

But there is no such nature in my .project file to start with.

In the current state, Eclipse is pretty unworkable for me because I have a hard time finding my files in the first place with the remaining "Explorers"...

Comment: can you clarify which part of this post answers the question?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today... Searched for information on how to fix and nothing helped.
While I noticed, what I was opened not Java perspective, but SVN. :)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/64vhx.png]

Comment: Thx !
For me it was also perspective dependent.
I was in JEE perspective and I switch to the Java one like you and the hierarchical come back.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a preset mindset bias against hierarchical presentation in Eclipse because this problem keeps reappearing at nearly every new Eclipse release. I suggest the people who develop and maintain Eclipse to change their default mindset from a flat presentation to a hierarchical mindset. Because the hierarchical presentation is more intuitive for programmers adept at large project namespaces.

This time is Eclipse 2023-12. But the solution is no longer just removing [Eclipse Faceted Project Properties].

This time I had to tickle Project Explorer this way:

1. Click the top right three little vertical dots to get this menu.
2. Deselect/unhighlight [Show Reference Library Nodes]
3. Set presentation to [hierarchical]
4. Then re-enable [Show Reference Library Nodes], if need to. Or not.

[Click on image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFsGQ.png)