# Why does Eclipse project explorer shows complete path on every level

Tags: eclipse

Directly after the upgrade to the latest version of Eclipse (4.23) the project explorer behaves abnormal. It shows the complete package path on **every** package hierarchy level.

The first image shows the abnormal view the second the expected view. As you can imagine with many hierarchy levels the view becomes quite confusing.

[image: Abnormal Appearance]

[image: Expected Appearance]

I've tried to change the package presantation, the project presentation and almost all other options in the project explorer view menu to no avail.

I assume this is a bug and will be fixed. Maybe someone has a workaround?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/71668323/6505250

Comment: Thanks. The workaround to disable facets is not an option to me.